# Sum the total time periods over a given day in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-4

I need a MySQL query for the following. I have a table of time periods as such below:

```
`active_periods`
+----+--------+---------+------------+------------+
| Id |   Day  | All Day | Start Time |  End Time  |
+----+--------+---------+------------+------------+
| 1  | Friday |    0    |  18:00:00  |  22:00:00  |
 ---- -------- --------- ------------ ------------
| 2  | Friday |    0    |  06:00:00  |  13:00:00  |
 ---- -------- --------- ------------ ------------
 INT  VARCHAR  TINYINT   TIME         TIME
```

Using a MySQL query, I need to be able to calculate these time periods and return the amount of **15 minute blocks** between these given time periods over the day of **Friday**. So from the table above I would get the answer of **44** 15 minutes blocks.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide more data like what datatype is your fields?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```sql
SELECT SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(end_time, start_time)) / 60 / 15) total
  FROM active_periods
 WHERE day = 'Friday'
```

Output:

```
| TOTAL |
---------
|    44 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f775/3)** demo

Comment: No, this only returns the sum of the first time period. I need it to sum both time periods. As I said, my desired result from the table above is **44** not 16.

Comment: this is a wrong query when I am changing the endtime value 13:00 to 15:00 then the result comes 52 which is not correct.

Comment: @Stewi Do you care to elaborate? Did you look at the sqlfiddle example I provided and the output??? It's 44. It does exactly that it calculates a number of 15-min block for each time period and sums it.

Comment: @BrokenHeartღ How is it wrong? Do you care to explain? Difference between 15:00 and 13:00 is +2 hours which is 8 15-min blocks. 44 + 8 = 52. Here is [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa091/1)

Comment: @Stewi The most probable cause of you getting 16 instead of 44 is that your real data is different from what you've posted as sample data in the question.

Comment: @Stewi, is there any chance your data has changed since you posted your question? I would guess that row ID 2 does not say "Friday" any more.

Comment: @peterm, I don't care whether the OP accepts your answer. To me, it's the right one. +1

Comment: It seems to be only doing it if the start time and end time is a VARCHAR, my datatypes are TIME.

Comment: @Stewi I've just updated the sqlfiddle example. It works perfectly fine with time datatype as expected.

Comment: I just deleted the records and added them again and the query is now saying 44, could anyone explain why this would happen? Sorry for any confusion, but I was only explaining what the query was returning me.

Comment: @Stewi You probably had trailing spaces or a typo in your data.

Answer (score 2):

This will return the Day and the number of 15 Minute Blocks (as a float).

```sql
SELECT `Day`, SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(`End Time`, `Start Time`)) / 60 / 15) AS `Periods` 
FROM `active_periods`
GROUP BY `Day`
```

Ex:

```
| Day    | Periods     |
------------------------
| Friday | 44.00000000 |
```

Comment: Are you sure that both records have the same value for the Day field? My guess is you have trailing spaces or something. Try running SELECT MD5(`Day`) FROM `active_periods`; and see if the hash that is returned is the same for all rows

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum( end_time - start_time ) / 900 from active_periods where day= 'Friday'
```